# Error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file

Tags: azure-devops, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

Currently my application references all three frameworks of .NET: .NET framework, .NET Standard & .NET 6. I am able to build all on my local machine using Visual Studio 2022, but with the build in Azure pipeline, only the .NET Standard and .NET framework apps are getting built.

I get this error:

> ##[error]Setup\Merge.Base\Base.wxs(198,0): Error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file '...._Out\Release\BaseExecutor.exe'.

This is the yml configuration for the .NET Standard application:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore netstandard2.0 projects'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        nugetConfigPath: '$(productname)\$(nugetConfigPath)'
      env:
          ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY: $(ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY)
```

And this is for the .NET framework and .net 6 application:

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Restore Nuget packages $(productname)'
      inputs:
        filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(productname)\RestoreNugetPackage.ps1'
      env:
        ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY: $(ARTIFACTORY__API_KEY)
```

Comment: Where is the yaml of .Net 6?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu-MSFT actually  in the second screenshot RestoreNugetPackage.ps1 poweshell script has written which will restore the .net 6 packages , but restoring is happend correctly for .net 6 , issue is wix (setup) project unable to find the .net 6 exe. but it able to find the same dll for .net 6 console application . could you please suggest me what are possible ways i can check to fix this .